# how to deploy dashboard(panel app) to windows IIS server

Tags: python, flask, iis, deployment, panel

I have already created panel app (python script) and it can run on the local host (panel serve xxx.py). I want to deploy it to IIS server. I'm not sure that it can do or not. So, how to do that?

I have find the same question and try to config it by myself, but it does not work

Additional, I try to use flask to serve panel script. This is `app.py`:

```py
import asyncio 
import panel as pn 
from aiohttp import web 
from Industry import Dashboard, gdf 

app = web.Application()

async def start_panel_server():
    await pn.serve(Dashboard(gdf).dashboard(), show=False, port=5006)

async def home(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    script = await loop.create_task(start_panel_server())
    return web.Response(text=script, content_type="text/html")

app.router.add_get("/", home)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    pn.serve(Dashboard(gdf).dashboard(), show=False, port=5000) 
    web.run_app(app)
```

However, when I run `python app.py` It can run on local, but when I configue it on IIS, It's error
This is the error.

```
TypeError: Application.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I have try to use flask to serve panel app but it still does not work on IIS server. The code and error already be added on my post.

Comment: Please forget about the legacy FastCGI approach and use HttpPlatformHandler instead, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the content in this link, if get any problems, please post the details of the problem.

[How to deploy your Dash app on the IIS windows server](https://medium.com/@b-nouri/how-to-deploy-your-dash-app-on-iis-windows-server-98a16b8707e1).

Comment: Thanks for your advise. So, this means that when deploying a panel app created by a Python script to a Windows IIS server, I typically need to use a web framework like Flask, along with a web server gateway interface (WSGI), to run the Python script as a web app. rights?

Comment: Yes, you can try it, if you have any questions, welcome to discuss.

Comment: I have try to use flask to serve panel script. But, It does not work on IIS server. I have write the flask code and error in the above comment.